# Sort an iterator of strings

Tags: java

I have an iterator of strings.

For sorting  i need to create a  list from it and sort it using `Collections.sort(list)`.

Is there any simple way to sort an iterator.

Comment: How did u get that `iterator`? from a `list`? how about passing the same `list`?

Comment: The iterator is an object which is solely designed for browsing over a collection. While there are some convenient functions which allow you to add or remove elements at *current* place, the iterator should not be used in your situation, because it would only make the code less understandable and possibly slower.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An Iterator is NOT a container, it is a utility for traversing over the elements of a container.
So if you only have access to the Iterator there is no way to change the order of iteration which is defined by the creator of this iterator.

If you can't change the original container, you'll have to gather the elements delivered by the iterator within a new Collection and sort them therein.

(A good approach to understand what is possible with iterators is to have a look at the Source-code of the JDK classes or to implement an own iterator)

Answer (score 7):

**Actually you cannot**,as Iterator is not an Collection.

If it is obvious,you can do

```
public static Iterator sortedIterator(Iterator it, Comparator comparator) {
      List list = new ArrayList();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
          list.add(it.next());
      }

      Collections.sort(list, comparator);
      return list.iterator();
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, the OP is asking if it is possible to sort _without_ copying the `Iterator` to another `Collection`.

Answer (score -3):

Use TreeSet or TreeMap. They are collections that are already sorted.

Comment: Yes, but they don't allow duplicates so they're not really substitutes for a `List`.

Comment: What do you mean by "a `Map` does"? A `Map` does not allow duplicate keys. I suppose you could put the `List` into a `Map` and store the number of repetitions of each key as an `Integer` in the value then use that to iterate but that is really hacking a `Map` to do something that it wasn't supposed to. Incidentally, in Java, a `Set` is a `Map` but with `null` values.

Comment: @renz: It doesn't allow duplicate keys. And since it sorts by key, a Map is in this context the same as a Set.