# Java printAll and print

Tags: java, printing

I need help with these two functions print and printall which really do what the title of the functions says

```
// Prints a directory of all StockItems with their associated
// price, in sorted order (ordered by SKU).
public void printAll() {
}

// Prints a directory of all StockItems from the given vendor, 
// in sorted order (ordered by SKU).
public void print(String vendor) {
}
```

Here is the full function below. DictionaryADT is a class that is used in implementing Hashtables and BST. The DictionaryADT just consists of functions. It has NOTHING to do with Map.

```
import data_structures.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class ProductLookup {


DictionaryADT<String,StockItem> dictionary;
private int maxSize;

public ProductLookup(int maxSize, DictionaryADT<String,StockItem> dictionary) {
    this(maxSize);
    this.dictionary = dictionary;
}

// Constructor.  There is no argument-less constructor, or default size
public ProductLookup(int maxSize) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
}

// Adds a new StockItem to the dictionary
public void addItem(String SKU, StockItem item) {
    dictionary.insert(SKU,item);
}

// Returns the StockItem associated with the given SKU, if it is
// in the ProductLookup, null if it is not.
public StockItem getItem(String SKU) {
    if (SKU == null)
        return null;
    return dictionary.getValue(SKU);
}

// Returns the retail price associated with the given SKU value.
// -.01 if the item is not in the dictionary
public float getRetail(String SKU) {
    if (!dictionary.contains(SKU))
        return (float) -.01;
    return getItem(SKU).getRetail();
}

public float getCost(String SKU) {
    if (!dictionary.contains(SKU))
        return (float) -.01;
    return getItem(SKU).getCost();
}

// Returns the description of the item, null if not in the dictionary.
public String getDescription(String SKU) {
    if (!dictionary.contains(SKU))
        return null;
    return getItem(SKU).getDescription();
}

// Deletes the StockItem associated with the SKU if it is
// in the ProductLookup.  Returns true if it was found and
// deleted, otherwise false.  
public boolean deleteItem(String SKU) {
    if (SKU == null)
        return false;
    return dictionary.remove(SKU);
}

// Prints a directory of all StockItems with their associated
// price, in sorted order (ordered by SKU).
public void printAll() {
}

// Prints a directory of all StockItems from the given vendor, 
// in sorted order (ordered by SKU).
public void print(String vendor) {
}

// An iterator of the SKU keys.
public Iterator<String> keys() {
    return dictionary.keys();

}

// An iterator of the StockItem values.    
public Iterator<StockItem> values() {
    return dictionary.values();
}
}
```

Comment: And what's your actual question? You've said what you want to do and given some code - so what problem are you having? What have you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: I've tried using the iterator and hasNext() to traverse and print the printall. I really don't know what traversal to do with just print

Comment: Iterator<StockItem> iterator = values();
     while (iterator.hasNext()) {
             System.out.println(item);
         }

Comment: That but didn't compile

Comment: Man I understand it looks like I put no work in, but when ever I put too much information no one answers. Now that I put enough to get something it will be closed for downvotes

Comment: Okay, so you want to know how to implement print() and printAll()?

Comment: Yeah basically. Like how do I traverse the whole list and print the SortedItems and how do I check the vendors of the SortedItems and print them

Comment: @FlameArc you don't explain where 'vendor' information comes from. Is that a member of StockItem class?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems like java's Iterator cannot be sorted using built in functions as [it is not a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16434566/1290264). You can, however, convert it to a `List` first, and then sort.

```
// Prints a directory of all StockItems with their associated
// price, in sorted order (ordered by SKU).
public void printAll() {
    // Convert the iterator of SKU's to a List
    List SKUList = new ArrayList();
    Iterator<String> keyIt = dictionary.keys();
    while( keyIt.hasNext() )
       SKUList.add(it.next());

    // Sort the SKU's
    Collections.sort(SKUList);

    // Print each item
    for(int i=0; i<SKUList.size(); i++){
        StockItem item = dictionary.getValue( SKUList.get(i) );
        // Print what you want here
    }       
}
```

Comment: Is the list in Collections.sort(list) SKULlist?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Also this will sort in natural order (for strings this is alphabetical). Depending on how you want your SKU's ordered, you might have to write your own comparator.