# How to sort an Iterable

Tags: java, sorting, iterable

I have a custom List (not a Collection!!) that implements Iterable. I don't implement List because that would bring way too much methods that I don't want, and that I don't need.

Some more Information about my CustomList:

- all members are final
- every CustomList can have a "SubList" which is another CustomList
- every CustomList has to have exactly one MyThing
- Example: say A is an Object of MyThing and B is an Object of MyThing, there can be one CustomList with only A (let's call it AList) and a CustomList with Item B and AList as Sublist.
- CustomList has a Constructor that can take an Array of MyThings

So this is my Class:

```
public class CustomList implements Iterable<MyThing> {

   private final CustomList sublist;

   private final MyThing thing;

   // getters and other methods
}
```

And I have a

```
Comparator<MyThing>
```

The MyThing:

```
public class MyThing {

   private final IntArrayList values;
   // more members and methods
}
```

I would like to get a sorted copy as CustomList of one of my CustomLists (If I don't need my Comparator that won't be a Problem, but that's how I solved it so far)

What I did so far is:

1. Transform my CustomList into a List
2. Sort that List (with the Comparator)
3. Transfer it back into a CustomList

This works fine, but I was wondering if there is another (perhaps more elegant way) to reach my goal.

Comment: What is `MyThing`? What are its fields and properties? What is your sorting criteria?

Comment: Could you explain why you implement an Iterable instead of extend some Collection?

Comment: Using Guava's `Ordering` (which extends `Comparator`), you can do [`ordering.sortedCopy(iterable)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#sortedCopy(java.lang.Iterable)). But this does basically what you are doing already.

Comment: The elegant way is to make your class implement `List` and not just `Iterable`. Why have you chosen not to do this?

Comment: Not to be confused with [sorting an `Iterator`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434526/sort-an-iterator-of-strings).

Comment: Do you want to modify your collection? Or do you want to produce a sorted view of your collection (changes to the content of your collection are reflected in the view)? Or do you want a sorted copy of your collection (changes to the content of the original collection are *not* reflected in the copy)?

Comment: Has been asked in many forms already. Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434526/sort-an-iterator-of-strings.

Comment: I don't think the "duplicates" suggested so far are true duplicates. The first doesn't make any sense, and the second is about sorting the elements of an `Iterator`, not doing something with the parent `Iterable` itself.

Comment: @erickson What can you do with an `Iterable` besides getting an `Iterator`? He would have to use the `Comparator<MyThing>` inside the `Iterator` to accomplish his goal, and as far as I see he needs a `Collection` to apply it to.

Comment: @ThomasChristensen You can't do anything else with an `Iterable`, but he's got a `CustomList`. The fact that it implements `Iterable` may be a red herring. Are his `CustomList` instances referenced as `Iterable` or `CustomList`? Could he create a new `sort()` method on `CustomList` (or a static method somewhere that accepts `CustomList`)? Or does he have `Iterable<MyThing>` references that need to be sorted?

Comment: @erickson Yes, but that is a lot of questions to ask that he should have given answers to.

Comment: @ThomasChristensen Yes, hopefully these comments will be read and used to improve the question.

Answer (score 5):

The core Java libraries don't expose a sort algorithm that works with an `Iterable`.

Built-in sorts copy elements to a temporary array. (`ArrayList` optimizes this by passing its internal array to the sort function.) A small improvement I recommend to your current approach is to copy your elements back and forth between an `Object[]` rather than a `List`. Then use `Arrays.sort()` instead of `Collections.sort()`. This saves creating a `List` object that isn't really used.

If you want to perform an in-place sort of your custom collection, you could implement a sort algorithm yourself. This isn't terribly hard, but more code means more bugs, more maintenance, and you won't benefit from improvements bundled with the JRE (like moving from "MergeSort") to "TimSort"). Only you can say whether the benefit is worth it.

Comment: but how to know size of iterator? You can not create Object[] without size. Because of that, ArrayList can handle your logic. I think so

Comment: @Dred The poster wrote a custom list, which is basically a linked list. They know how many elements they have in the list, whether that's because they are caching a count, or  by traversing the links. For a more general solution to sort the elements of an `Iterable` type, it would be convenient to add elements to some kind of `List` as you describe.

Answer (score 4):

Create a Stream from the Iterable and then sort the Stream.

```
CustomList list = new CustomList();
Stream<MyThing> sorted = StreamSupport.stream(
        list.spliterator(), false)
    .sorted();
```